# How can I use Selenium 2 to look for two potential elements?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Super newbie here.

I am testing a page that either returns a list of tweets, or if none are available, a no results page.  So I have two possible acceptable outcomes.  I am trying to write an assert in Selenium 2 that tests for either element, but if neither appears, return an error.

I am using the page object model and I wrote the following:

```
Assert.assertTrue((iu.twitterUsername().isDisplayed()) || (iu.noData().isDisplayed()), "Page is not loading")
```

However, I am getting an element not found on the first part of my OR statement when the no data page is displayed.  I thought the point of 'isDisplayed' was to check if the element is there.  Why am I getting an element not found error?  Obviously its not there, and I want to move onto the second part of my OR statement.

Is there a better way to write this when there are two possible acceptable results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebElement.isDisplayed() method doesn't tell you whether or not an element is there; it tells you whether it is displayed on the page (as opposed to being hidden).

You can use the WebDriver.findElement() method to test whether or not an element has loaded; it will throw a NoSuchElementException if it hasn't. Your method might look like this:

```
public static boolean isElementLoaded(WebDriver driver, By findBy) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(findBy));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    } 
    return true;     
}
```

You can alter how long WebDriver waits for the element to load with something like the following, which changes it to five seconds:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Alternatively, you can create a method that will poll for the element until a timeout is reached.

Comment: thanks for the help. Maybe I am using the wrong method.  I want to use selenium 2 to look for an element, and if it isn't on the page, have a testng assert throw a failure.  However, before testng can run the assert, I get the NoSuchElemmentException.  Is there a better way to verify an element is present on the page?

I tried your link and it didnt work.

Comment: @Joe I think there's something fundamental you're missing here. `findElement()` and `findElements()` (and **only** those methods) are used to determine the presence or absence of an element on the page. If an element isn't on the page, `findElement()` throws a `NoSuchElementException`. That's the way the API works, there's no way around it. If you don't want to catch the exception when the element isn't on the page, you can use `findElements()`, which returns an empty list, meaning that if the `size()` of the returned list is 0, the element is not present.

Comment: I have removed the link as I no longer think it's useful in this case; you can use a WebDriverWait if you wish to poll until the element appears. I have also added an example method above demonstrating catching the exception and returning a boolean, which I think is what you are ultimately after.

Comment: @JimEvans That is what I ended up doing. I am using FindElements, then assert size()>0.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: @codemiller , I am now using try catch blocks whenever I am using FindElement, so that I can throw my own error.  Since I use testng, I use a similar try catch block, then an assert.fail.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
```

Assuming you're doing something before looking for the element I'd suggest using WebDriverWait then throw and catch exception if you don't find the element in the alloted time.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
try {
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(By.id(id)));
} catch (ElementNotFound e) {};
element = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
```